# Why does leaving the dot out in foldLeft cause a compilation error?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Can anyone explain why I see this compile error for the following when I omit the dot notation for applying the `foldLeft` function?(version 2.9.2)

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3)
res19: List[Int] = List(1 ,2 ,3)

scala> l foldLeft(1)(_ * _)
<console>:9: error: Int(1) does not take parameters
                    l foldLeft(1)(_ * _)
                                    ^
```

but

```
scala> l.foldLeft(1)(_ * _) 
res27: Int = 6
```

This doesn't hold true for other higher order functions such as `map` which doesn't seem to care whether I supply the dot or not.

I don't think its an associativity thing because I can't just invoke `foldLeft(1)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's because foldLeft is curried. As well as using the dot notation, you can also fix this by adding parentheses:

```
scala> (l foldLeft 1)(_ * _)
res3: Int = 6
```

Oh - and regarding your comment about not being able to invoke `foldLeft(l)`, you can, but you need to partially apply it like this:

```
scala> (l foldLeft 1) _
res3: ((Int, Int) => Int) => Int = <function1>
```

Comment: thanks Constructive note, The complete answer to my question lives in the first comment you made on Regis's post regarding how the parser attacks the expression.

Answer (score 3):

Omitting the dot is possible because of scala's syntactic support for the infix notation, which expects 3 parts:

```
leftOperand operator rightOperand.
```

But because `foldLeft` had two list of parameters, you end up with 4 parts at the syntactic level: `l` `foldLeft` `(1)` `(_ * _)`

Which does not fit infix notation, hence the error.

Comment: That might be a good rule of thumb for understanding when infix notation is useful, but I'm not sure that it's entirely accurate. It is possible to call `foldLeft` using infix notation (as shown in my earlier answer). The problem is that the parser is parsing `l fold left(1)(_ * _)` as `l foldLeft((1)(_ * _))` instead of `(l foldLeft(1))(_ * _)`.

Comment: Well your work around actually proves my point. You are forcing partial application of foldLeft so as to have 3 parts, which makes infix notation possible. The result is a function, that you immediately call.

Comment: Sorry - this is just pedantry on my part, but the error is not due to infix notation being rejected by the compiler. It's due to the compiler trying to apply `(_ * _)` to `(1)`, which it can't.

Comment: (grr - just noticed that my Mac "corrected" `foldLeft` to `fold left` in my earlier comment above)

Comment: I did not say that it's due to infix notation being rejected. Sorry I was probably too elusive, and potentially misleading. 
The point is that `foldLeft (1) (_ * _)` does not fit infix notation. Whatever else the compiler can try to make sense of 
this expression, this will certainly not be what was intended (luckily here it just does not compile, but in other similar 
situations it could compile and do something unexpected).

Comment: Ah - got you. Fair enough :-)