# Scala - foldLeft type inference fail

Tags: scala, types, fold

In my code, I have the following:

```
  type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]

  def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = {
    val yMap = y.toMap
    x foldLeft (List[(Char, Int)]()) {  // ERROR
        case (a: List[(Char, Int)], xe: (Char, Int)) =>
        if(yMap.contains(xe._1)) (xe._1 -> (xe._2 - yMap(xe._1))) :: a
        else a
    }
  }
```

It fails on compile-time, at the `{` that is right before the error mark in the code. The error message is the following:

> missing parameter type for expanded function The argument types of an
>   anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5) Expected type was:
>   Int

1) How could that be? As far as I can see, there is no room for misinterpretation of type information here, and I find a lot of such examples over the internet. How can I fix that?

2) Why is it thinking that the expected type is `Int` after all?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904978/why-does-leaving-the-dot-out-in-foldleft-cause-a-compilation-error/12908899#12908899

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error occurs because you wrote `xs foldLeft (init) (f)` instead of `(xs foldLeft init)(f)` or `xs.foldLeft(init)(f)`.

The former does not work, because Scalas operator notation rules allow only to leave the dot and parentheses if a call occurs in form `obj method param`, which is not the case with `foldLeft` because it has two parameter lists.