# foldLeft with Double

Tags: scala, foldleft

I' am trying to use `foldLeft` to calculate the sum of all `Double` in a `Vector`.
Using `reduce` works fine but I just can't figure out why it doesn't with `foldLeft`

```
scala> val prices = Vector(20.0, 9.5,8.4,9.1)
prices: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Double] = Vector(20.0, 9.5, 8.4, 9.1)

scala> prices reduce (_ + _)
res0: Double = 47.0

scala> prices reduce ((total, price) => total + price)
res1: Double = 47.0

scala> prices foldLeft (0.0) (_ + _)
<console>:9: error: Double(0.0) does not take parameters
              prices foldLeft (0.0) (_ + _)
                                ^
```

I googled for some examples using `foldLeft` with `Double` and the above syntax seems to work

Anyone can explain where the problem is from ?

Thank you

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904978/why-does-leaving-the-dot-out-in-foldleft-cause-a-compilation-error

Comment: @Mik378 - Thanks a lot - I missed this post

Comment: Just a logical story about brackets and precedance :)

Comment: Thanks for bringing up this question, up-voted; a side note, `prices sum` conveys the same semantics in this very case :)