# Error when calling a method in Scala with a " " rather than a "."

Tags: scala

Why does the first pair of method calls (using `mkString`) both work, while the second pair of method calls (using `fold`) fail when I replace the "." with a " "? What is the parameter type that is missing?

I'm using Scala version 2.11.0.

```
scala> List("a", "b", "c").mkString("")
res0: String = abc

scala> List("a", "b", "c") mkString("")
res1: String = abc

scala> List("a", "b", "c").fold(""){(x,y)=> x++y}
res2: String = abc

scala> List("a", "b", "c") fold(""){(x,y)=> x++y}
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type
              List("a", "b", "c") fold(""){(x,y)=> x++y}
                                            ^
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type
              List("a", "b", "c") fold(""){(x,y)=> x++y}
```

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904978/why-does-leaving-the-dot-out-in-foldleft-cause-a-compilation-error/12905062#12905062

Comment: it is. should I flag it as a dupe?

Comment: There should be a FAQ which notes that "omitting the dot" is not a thing.  It would also say the parens and curly braces are not interchangeable. These things look like magic at first.  SO should have a feature that counts duplicates and generates FAQs on that basis.